# Why can "opposed to" be used directly after a conjunction or a preposition?

Tags: meaning

In the sentence below, why use not "subject+verb" but "the past tense verb (opposed)" after the conjunction "as"?
In the sentence below, why use not "noun(or gerund)" but "the past tense verb (opposed)" after the preposition "in"?

> We're going to Florida for our vacation this year, **as opposed to**
>   the local beach.
>
> VDC is an abbreviation for “volts DC” DC stands for direct current
>   which means voltage is constant **in opposed to** AC which is
>   alternating current that alternates from positive to negative.

Does it mean "We're going to Florida for our vacation this year, as that we're going to Florida for our vacation this year is opposed to the local beach"?

Does it mean "DC stands for direct current which means voltage is constant in DC being opposed to AC"?

Where is the "subject + verb" after the conjunction?
Where is the "noun" after the preposition?

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect.  It should also be *"as opposed to"*.  If you want to use "in" then you can say *"in opposition to"*.

Comment: Here, I think "opposed" is passive voice, not past tense.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you are asking about

> **as opposed to**

has the meaning

> **in contrast to**
>   **instead of**
>   **which is different from**

What's being *"opposed"* is the usual routine of going to the local beach.

Your second sentence is incorrect since the idiom is

> **as opposed to**

So, the complete sentence as your first example is

> We're going to Florida for our vacation this year, **as opposed to** *going to* the local beach.

Comment: If so, does "as opposed to going to the local beach" mean "as going to the local beach opposed" ?  does "as opposed to the local beach" mean "as the local beach opposed". the "subject" after the conjunction("as") is "to going to the local beach" or "the local beach"?